# Strength of the multi-pass guarantee for forward iterators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

Consider the definition of Forward iterators in the standard (draft n4659, [forward.iterators]/27.2.5):

> A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>
> - `X` satisfies the requirements of an input iterator (27.2.3),
> - `X` satisfies the `DefaultConstructible` requirements (20.5.3.1),
> - If `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a constant iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`,
> - The expressions in Table 97 are valid and have the indicated semantics, and
> - Objects of type `X` offer the *multi-pass guarantee*, described below.
>     [note omitted]
>     Two dereferenceable iterators `a` and `b` of type `X` offer the multi-pass guarantee if:
>
>   - `a == b` implies `++a == ++b` and
>   - `X` is a pointer type or the expression `(void)++X(a), *a` is equivalent to the expression `*a`.
>
> [ Note: The requirement that `a == b` implies `++a == ++b` (which is not true for input and output iterators) and the removal of the restrictions on the number of the assignments through a mutable iterator (which applies to output iterators) allows the use of multi-pass one-directional algorithms with forward iterators. - end note ]
>
> [table 97 omitted]
>
> - If `a` and `b` are equal, then either `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable or else neither is dereferenceable.
> - If `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object.

The intent of the multi-pass guarantee seems seems to be about allowing code like:

```
*iter <---------------------------------------------------
X iter_copy(iter);                                       |
/* do something with iter_copy */                        |
++iter_copy; ... ++iter_copy;                            |
/* iter has not changed, and *iter now is equivalent     |
 * to *iter before the operations on iter_copy */        |
*iter <---------------------------------------------------
```

However formally the multi-pass guarantee only seems to imply that doing a copy of iter and incrementing the copy leaves `*iter` unchanged, and a second subsequent increment to `iter_copy` might change `*iter`.

Now your first thought might be "duh, induction!", but it seems to fall short of the desired result; all it says is if we do a copy of `iter_copy` and increment *that* copy, then `*iter_copy` is unchanged but it says nothing about the original `*iter`.

**Question: Is it possible to show that the multi-pass guarantee as specified implies what is intended ?**

Comment: The requirement doesn't say that `*iter_copy` remains unchanged, it says that `*iter` remains unchanged.

Comment: Note that `(void)++(++X(a)), *a` being equivalent to `*a` is not true; if `a` is one-before-`end()` a double increment is UB, so the first is UB while the second is not.  However, if `*iter_copy` cannot invalidate `*a`, then netiher can `(void)++X(iter_copy), *iter_copy` as the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Yakk but past-the-end iterators are not dereferenceable and the requirement is "if a and b are dereferenceable then ..."

Comment: but does it really says that? (ignoring the cast to void which is just because of the operator comma, and assuming that all the iterators are valid so no past-the-end edge case) It says that if I have `iter` and make a copy `iter_copy` of it, then after `++iter_copy` `*iter` is unchanged. Then I can make another copy `iter_copy_copy` of `iter_copy`, increment `iter_copy_copy` and the requirement says that `*iter_copy` is unchanged. But it seems to me that nothing is said about the original `*iter`. It might have been changed by the second increment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's *possible* to come up with a type that meets all the forward iterator guarantees but isn't perfectly multi-pass.

```
class Evil {
    int* p;
    size_t idx;

public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;

    Evil() : p(nullptr), idx(0) { }
    Evil(int* p, size_t idx) : p(p), idx(idx) { }
    Evil(Evil const& ) = default;
    Evil& operator=(Evil const& ) = default;
    ~Evil() = default;

    // only p participates in comparison
    bool operator==(Evil const& rhs) const {
        return p == rhs.p && idx % 2 == rhs.idx % 2; 
    }
    bool operator!=(Evil const& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }

    // incrementing is sort of destructive
    Evil& operator++() {
        ++idx;
        ++p[idx % 2];
        return *this;
    }
    Evil operator++(int) {
        auto tmp = *this;
        ++*this;
        return tmp;
    }

    int& operator*() { return p[idx % 2]; }
};
```

Let's go through the requirements:

- `a == b` implies `++a == ++b`. Check. `operator++()` doesn't even affect equality.
- `(void)*a, *a` is equivalent to `*a`. Check, dereferencing isn't destructive.
- `(void)++X(a), *a` is equivalent to `*a`. Check. Incrementing one changes the *other* int, not the one this iterator currently "points" to. So this condition also holds.
- `a == b` iff `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object. Check.

However, `(void)++++X(a), *a` is definitely not equivalent to `*a`. You'll get the same `int` back, it'll just be one larger.

The fact that I can come up with a comically impractical iterator that doesn't meet the guarantee might suggest that there's an actual practical one that also doesn't meet the guarantee. There's a lot of C++ out there.

Comment: @Angew Corrected, I think?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about something like that. However this begs the question: Should the multi-pass guarantee be strengthened since it seems that the algorithms in <algorithm> requiring Forward iterators assume that the "strong" multi-pass guarantee holds ?